# Use a command inside Zim Desktop Wiki with run command func

Tags: command-line

There is a function inside Zim Desktop Wiki program for run a commandline command but I'm getting error.

For paste a date, it works. (My command is: `date "+Date: %d %b %Y - %H:%M:%S"` )

But when I want to run an alias (For example: `zim_up` alias for this command: `cd ~/Google && grive`) it doesn't work.. I'm getting error as "No such file or directory".. (I just want to update my notes with this alias and it's important for me.)

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably uses `/bin/sh` to launch the command, not your shell. If you need to use an alias, try

```
bash -lic zim_up
```

I'm assuming your shell is bash.

- `-l` use a login shell so your .bash_profile is sourced
- `-i` force the shell to be interactive so aliases are activated
- `-c zim_up` run your alias

Comment: Hi again, it's not working on Ubuntu 16.04. Is there any way you know?

Comment: So, what changed?

Comment: I'm translating the error message to English: "bash -lic zim_up returned a non-zero exit status: 1

Comment: What happens when you run your alias at a shell prompt?

Comment: Is shell prompt mean "terminal (ctrl+alt+T)" ? If it is, when I use the alias in terminal, it's working fine. There is no problem. Grive reading my directory and saying that: "Sync is finished!"

Comment: And what is the exit status? Run `zim_up; echo $?`

Comment: sorry for late reply.. it's turning out "0".